# What is the default font in Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts

What is the default font in Ubuntu?

Could someone tell me please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default font for Ubuntu is called Ubuntu.

Quote from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(typeface):

"The Ubuntu Font Family is the default font for the current and development releases of the Ubuntu operating system and is used for the Ubuntu project branding"

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought it was a windows sans-serif type of font

Answer (score 1):

"Ubuntu" is default font for Ubuntu OS

Visit [this site](http://font.ubuntu.com/) to test and download the Ubuntu Font Family.